# How to gain mass and wight

Tags: muscle-mass

I am 6-2 I weigh 8 stone and I can’t seem to work out if working on one muscle a day is better than working on a group of muscle a day I also have a fast metabolism and I can’t seen to get a good routine so if someone could help that would be much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to the site! This is a popular question, and as such has many answers available if you look at the "related" column. However, I am concerned about your actual weight, you say you are 6'2" with a stated weight of 8 stone (112 lbs)? If this is accurate, this is something you should talk with a medical professional, as you are severely, possibly dangerously underweight.

Answer (score 0):

You need only follow a reputable program that matches your goals while also eating in a caloric surplus that includes a sufficient protein intake (1.8g per kg of bodyweight or 0.8g per pound).